# Changed the turbo, now the car won’t start?

Tags: starting

So basically I have a Vauxhall corsa D 1.3 CDTI 2008, I recently swapped the turbo out with a replacement one (same turbo), when I put it all back together I went to start the car and it just turns over but doesn’t actually start, turn over speed is good, so it’s not the battery plus I’ve had it connected to jump leads whilst turning it over. I noticed that one of the leak off pipes had come away from the injector and was leaking fuel everywhere, so I re-attached it started the car again, still no luck.

I can’t think of any possible causes, I had the car jacked up on a axel stand on one side over night, I thought it could be air in the fuel line from when the leak off pipe was disconnected, but I’m not sure that would cause a no start. Maybe a flooded engine from leaving it up on one side overnight?

Any help as to what to do next would help. thanks

Comment: The motor's cranking, so the battery and starter are OK, but the motor doesn't start because something's interfering with the fuel delivery to the cylinders (this is a diesel, right?).  While a fuel injection pipe might have been dislodged or broken, no-start also likely to be caused by inadvertently dislodging or disconnecting an electrical connection. "Look where you last worked" is a fine troubleshooting maxim. Carefully examine the motor and the injection system and injector wiring for disturbed or broken or disconnected wiring.

Comment: Yes it is diesel, I checked the area where I replaced the turbo I didn’t touch anything electrical at all whilst removing or replacing, I made sure I didn’t catch anything with the tools and nothing seems broken

Comment: I would consider removing one fuel injector from the cylinder head, and cranking the motor (as if to start it) while pointing the injector into a bucket. If fuel doesn't spray or dribble out of the injector, you will have confirmed that the FI system isn't operating, perhaps because of an undiscovered wiring fault, or because the system has suddenly suffered a pump failure or a clogged fuel filter. The former case is much more likely. You might ask a friend to look at things; she or he might see something that you've missed.